# How to Randomly Generate SKNodes but Ensuring Gap

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am making a game with Sprite Kit and I am stuck with this!

What I am trying to do is generate obstacles which are about 50x50 from the right side of the screen and applying force to them. This is all fine and working but what I want is to ensure that there is always a "Gap" so that the "Player Node" can always pass through the objects.

Kind of like a space shooter game but without the gun.

At the moment I am just using two functions that generate a random Y position from the the bottom of the screen to the top.

```
//Custom Functions

static inline CGFloat skRandf(){
return rand() / (CGFloat) RAND_MAX;
}
static inline CGFloat skRand(CGFloat low, CGFloat high){
return skRandf() * (high - low) +low;
}
```

Then am using this to put the node in position:

```
obstical.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width + obstical.size.width, skRand(0 + ground.size.height, self.mainSize.height));
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: You maybe have to reverse the way you think of your issue. Maybe by defining the gap before and then putting the objects.

Comment: Store your on screen objects in an array and check distance gaps for newly created object against those in the array.